# Detect device aspect ratio

Tags: jquery, html

The plugin **fullpageScroll** allows to deactivate its plugin at a certain point (for mobile sites). so by setting `responsive: 750` the plugin is deactivated whenever the browsers width is less then 750px.

I want to extend this by checking the aspect ratio as well. So whenever the `$(window).width()/$(window).height() <= 1.32)` I want to although deactivate the plugin.

The code that does the check named above goes like this:

```
function responsive(){
    if(options.responsive){

        var isResponsive = container.hasClass('fp-responsive');
        if ($(window).width() < options.responsive ){
            if(!isResponsive){
                $.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(false, 'internal');
                $('#fp-nav').hide();
                container.addClass('fp-responsive');
            }
        }else if(isResponsive){
            $.fn.fullpage.setAutoScrolling(originals.autoScrolling, 'internal');
            $('#fp-nav').show();
            container.removeClass('fp-responsive');
        }
    }
}
```

I am not able to implement the second check for the aspect ratio into this code. I appreciate every help or suggestion!

Comment: You could use https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: you are using comma in your if comparison, you should be using dot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this then implement your function where the console.log is

```
$( window ).resize(function() {   
    if($(window).width()/$(window).height() <= 1.32){
        console.log("Do stuff here")
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. I am not able to insert your code into mine. I have updated my question, if you know a solution, please let me know. Thanks for your help and your good piece of code!